# Add class to erb element

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, erb

```
<%= d.box, :class => "something" %>
```

What is my syntax error here? Can't figure it out. Class is not properly adding to erb variable.

Error message:

> syntax error, unexpected =>, expecting :: or '[' or '.' ...pend=(
>   d.box, :class => "something" );@output_buffer.safe... ... ^

Comment: It looks good. Did you inspect the element in the browser? Maybe the class is there but you don't load the css file or `something` class is missing in the css file or with wrong name there?

Comment: I have this error: syntax error, unexpected =>, expecting :: or '[' or '.' ...pend=( d.box, :class => "something" );@output_buffer.safe... ... ^

Comment: Try: `<%= d.box, class: "something" %>`

Comment: @MihailPetkov still not working

Comment: I added a full comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't add class to a simple value (`d.box`). ERB will render the value of `d.box`, let's say 123. So you are trying to add class to `123` which is not a html element. You should add class name to the parent html element.

Comment: I have the same problem, and it doesn't inherit parent html element's class. I don't know why. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

`<%= %>` means just run code and print on view.
so, `<%= d.box, :class => "something" %>` raise error.

I think you tried call helper method.
Show document about [TagHelper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper.html#method-i-tag)